# How to set WildFly 9.0.1.Final httpUri encoding

Tags: encoding, wildfly

For the reason that I want to use `JavaEE7` and `JPA2.1`, I turned to `WildFly9.0.1` Final which meets my requirement.

`WildFly9.0.1` Final is using *undertow* as the Web Server.

Chinese Characters(in UTF-8 encoding) from web browser transferred to the jboss Server turned TO Garbled words，below is the log:

```
2015-08-02 18:58:38,893 INFO  com.gcable.action.people.people_type.PeopleTypeAction.printHttpRequest:76
 - peopleTypes[0].pt_name=[Ljava.lang.String;@3e31e9ad[{￨ﾌﾃ￥ﾾﾷ￨ﾐﾨ}]
```

I am going mad! God save me!

I have tried this in `standalone.xml`:

```
<servlet-container name="default" default-encoding="UTF-8">
```

But it doesn't work.

Also I have tried to add `jboss-web.xml` in `WEB-INF` in my deployed war:

```
<jboss-web version="9.0" xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_9_0.xsd">
<default-encoding>UTF-8</default-encoding>
```

It doesn't work too.

Comment: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/240707?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-2533

Comment: Hi,happy,have you tried the none-english with wildfly?Those all I have tried.Doesn't work.I doubt it is a bug of wildfly.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by setting the encoding in the http-listener of the standalone.xml (i use the standalone-full.xml but i guess it makes no difference)

```
<http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" url-charset="ISO-8859-1"/>
```

Sorry for the late answer but i got the same problem today. Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Kind of bizarre, for some reason sometimes wildfly deletes that url-charset from standalone.xml for me, I revoked the right of write now it fully functional. However this resolved our problem after 30 hours of research. I would upvote it twice if I could.

Comment: I noticed the same behavior when editing the standalone-full.xml while wildfly is running, so i always stop the server before any editing of the standalone-full.xml and then restart it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally tried to down-grade my JPA2.1 to 2.0.
Jboss EAP 6.2 perfectly encodes the none-english characters.

By the way,
I found sth [here](http://mariemjabloun.blogspot.com/2014/03/use-jboss-jpa-21-and-hibernate-43-on.html) to make JBOSS EAP6 which in fact is a JavaEE6 Container to USE JPA2.1 instead of using 2.0